# How can I solve the error: entity GroceryItems is not key value coding-compliant for the key "hasLocations"

Tags: core-data, crash, entity-relationship

What follows is everything I can possibly think of as background to try and identify the source of the error.  I will, of course, provide any other information that may be helpful.  Thanks in advance for your help.

I am new to Core Data, and I have an entity named GroceryItem. It has a to-many relationship named hasLocations, which I am trying to query with the following code:

```
itemObject = (GroceryItem *)[GroceryItem itemNameToObject:itemName];

if (itemObject != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"initAndFillItemLocationsTable got an item named %@", itemObject.name]);
}

if (itemLocations != nil)
{
    [itemLocations removeAllObjects];
}

if (itemObject != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Before mutable set assignment");

    NSMutableSet *mutableLocationsSet = [itemObject mutableSetValueForKeyPath:@"hasLocations"];
```

I see the "Before mutable set assignment" message in the output, followed by

2013-01-23 03:27:14.898 Grocery Manager[6431:11603] initAndFillItemLocationsTable got an item named Cream Cheese
2013-01-23 03:27:14.899 Grocery Manager[6431:11603] Before mutable set assignment
2013-01-23 03:27:14.901 Grocery Manager[6431:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity GroceryItems is not key value coding-compliant for the key "hasLocations".'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x15eb012 0x1410e7e 0x1673fb1 0x11c304 0xe298db 0xb8374 0xe298db 0xec3180 0xec31de 0x17450 0xaa5c 0x439817 0x439882 0x439b2a 0x450ef5 0x450fdb 0x451286 0x451381 0x451eab 0x4524a3 0x452098 0x7adda3 0x79fad9 0x79fb54 0x407899 0x407b3d 0xe0ee83 0x15aa376 0x15a9e06 0x1591a82 0x1590f44 0x1590e1b 0x24377e3 0x2437668 0x35865c 0x27bd 0x26e5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

The contents of the GroceryItem class definition are:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface GroceryItem : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *hasLocations;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *containedInIngredients;

@end

@interface GroceryItem (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addHasLocationsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)removeHasLocationsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)addHasLocations:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeHasLocations:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addContainedInIngredientsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)removeContainedInIngredientsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)addContainedInIngredients:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeContainedInIngredients:(NSSet *)values;

+(GroceryItem *)itemNameToObject:(NSString *)itemName;
```

I have verified in the database editor that the class GroceryItem is assigned to the entity GroceryItem.

I read the Key-Value Coding Programming Guide and implemented the following code in GroceryItem.m:

```
- (void)addHasLocationsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value
{
    [self.hasLocations setByAddingObject:value];
}

- (void)removeHasLocationsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value
{
    NSMutableSet *mutable = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:self.hasLocations];

    [mutable removeObject:value];

    self.hasLocations = mutable;
}

- (void)addHasLocations:(NSSet *)values
{
    [self.hasLocations setByAddingObjectsFromSet:values];
}

- (void)removeHasLocations:(NSSet *)values
{
    NSMutableSet *mutable = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:self.hasLocations];

    for (id obj in [mutable allObjects])
    {
        if ([values containsObject:obj])
        {
            [mutable removeObject: obj];
        }
    }
    self.hasLocations = mutable;
}

- (NSUInteger)countOfHasLocations
{     
    return [self.hasLocations count];
}

- (NSEnumerator *)enumeratorOfHasLocations
{
    return [self.hasLocations objectEnumerator];
}

- (GroceryLocation *)memberOfHasLocations:(GroceryLocation *)anObject
{
    return [self.hasLocations member:anObject];

}
```

The static itemNameToObject function looks like this:

```
+(GroceryItem *)itemNameToObject:(NSString *)itemName
{
    GroceryItem *groceryItem;

    groceryItem = nil;

    if (itemName != nil)
    {
        GroceryManagerAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"GroceryItems" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

        [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", itemName]];

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *groceryItemObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        NSInteger countOfGroceryItems = [groceryItemObjects count];

        if (countOfGroceryItems == 1)
        {
            groceryItem = (GroceryItem *)[groceryItemObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }

    return groceryItem;
}
```

Comment: 1) Your entity is called "GroceryItems" and the class "GroceryItem", so you should double-check that the correct class is assigned to the entity (and perhaps use the same name to avoid confusion). - 2) Why do you write the accessor methods yourself? Using "Editor -> Create NSManagedObject subclasses ..." is much less error-prone.

Comment: Thanks, Martin R!  I had not noticed that the error said "GroceryItems."  This looks like a migration issue, because a recent version of my model changed that entity from "GroceryItems" to "GroceryItem."

Comment: 2) I did use Editor->CreateNSManagedObject Subclass, but I guess I got confused by the function declarations in the .h file without implementations for them in the .m file. So at that point I tried to implement them myself, hoping that doing so might fix this error.  More proof that I'm quite new at this...

Comment: Your comment got me started on the path, but I'm still getting the error.  I'm not sure how to get rid of whatever is hanging around from the old version of my model. I have code in my AppDelegate that uses the NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption option, and I don't know where else to look.

Comment: @MartinR - Problem solved!  If you make your comment an answer, I will upvote it. Complete problem explanation: I had failed to select the newest version of my xcdatamodel file.  Some parts of my code were able to get what they needed by looking for "GroceryItems," because that was the entity the (old version) active model had in it.  But the code above where I had the crash was not able to get the relationship with GroceryItems, because it didn't exist in that version.  The model migrations were so messed up that I decided to start from scratch.  Moral: be very careful about model versions!

Comment: I'm glad that you solved your problem. I have posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(From the comments:)* The crash is caused by the fact that the entity is declared as "GroceryItems", but "hasLocations" is a property of the class "GroceryItem". The fetch request returns an array of "GroceryItems" objects, which do not respond to the "hasLocations" method.

Also it is not normally necessary to implement the Core Data accessor methods, they are dynamically created at runtime.